# How to set alias correctly in Network Solutions CNAME to use Amazon s3 bucket?

Tags: dns

I've create my s3 bucket with the same name as my site, `awsmd.org`
I've enabled website content and can see the page at

http://awsmd.org.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/index.html
also at
https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/awsmd.org/index.html

I have the domain previously registered (months ago) awsmd.org in Network solutions.

I believe I have to update the CNAME records?

I have made changes and current the display page looks like this.

[image]

I think there may be a bug - that doublename stuff in the alias column is weird.  However when I open up the detail page I see

[image]

Is that set correctly there?

Using http://awsmd.org/index.html I am currently seeing the aws under construction page, but I only recently (last hour) deleted the A records pointing to under construction pages

Am I doing this right.  Do I just need to wait for DNS propogation ?
I see others have had issues using Network Solutions UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typo was from how I (incorrectly) used the alias, you actually use

```
@
```

for the plain (no www) name, e.g. host.org

and

```
www
```

for the www.host.org host

It ends up showing as follows which seems odd for the plain @ one but is apparently correct.

[image]